# who is responsible for cart session management?

Tags: php, laravel, session

I designed a cart for a site I did recently. For my persistence I chose sessions. Currently the cart is responsible for its own session management. When the `Cart` is instantiated, the `constructor` restores the cart from the session, using a `Session` facade. When the `Cart` is destroyed, the `destructor` saves the current state of the cart to the session, again using the facade.  I know this is not good, and is in need of a refactor.

I see 2 possible routes for the session management, so my question is, whose *responsibility* is it to manage the session? Should it be the responsibility of the controller to save and restore the cart to and from the session? **OR** do I inject a session layer into the cart, and the cart still handles it internally?

I will say I've had mixed results using the php `__destruct()`, due to the fact that it can be called in any order during the shutdown sequence. I think I'd like to move away from using it because of its unpredictable behavior (unless someone convinces me otherwise).

One benefit I had with the cart handling its own session storage, was that I only had to handle the saving and restoring in **1** place. If I go the controller route, I imagine I will need to `restore()` and `save()` it for every controller method it is needed in. I'm not opposed to that if cleans up the dependencies of the Cart, but obviously we always prefer to write less code.

I know this question is a little open ended and may invite opinion based answers, so please provide specific examples of things you've tried that have or have not worked, and the pros and cons of them.

Thanks!

Comment: no real requirement here, as long as the session is active the cart is active. why do you ask?

Comment: probably 30 minutes, whatever the default is in my php config file.

Comment: It doesn't matter. By using dependency injection it's simple to choose another implementation

Comment: no, it's gone. while that is a valid option, it is a completely different discussion. I have opted for sessions with this project because it fits the business needs. my question is specifically about the responsibility of session management.

Answer (score 0):

No session handling in the controller. That's for delegating and consolidating.

Sessions should be handled by the session handler. With dependency injection you can inject the handler in the constructor. This is nice for maintainability, scalability and testability.

Comment: I agree. I have a session handler injected. But somebody still needs to tell the session handler to set or get variables. Should that be the cart or the controller?

Comment: Using dependency injection you can use methods of that object. In this case the controller gets input and could pass that to the method(s) of its DI object.

Comment: It's better to implement an interface for your session handler like CartStorageHandlerInterface. The constructor should expect an object that implements this interface. So it's simple for you to make an other implementation, e.g. SessionStorageHandler,  DatabaseStorageHandler, FileStorageHandler, etc. All implements CartStorageHandlerInterface. Very OOP! ;-)

Comment: so are you suggesting injecting the session handler into the `Cart`, and the `Cart` internally restores and saves itself using that injected session handler?

Comment: It's possible you injectthe session handler in the constructor of the controller. This object contains the logic to handle sessions. Input for this can be provided by the controller, but the controller doesn't know anything about 'how to handle sessions'.

Comment: correct. I already inject the session handler into the controller. so now the question is, should that controller 'get' and 'set' the cart, or should the controller inject the session handler into the `Cart`, and the `Cart` 'gets' and 'sets' itself.